# What can be planted on a shady, damp slope to help remove weeds?

Tags: weed-control

I am removing ferns and brambles from a steep, damp and shaded hillside. Proper planting will come later but first I want to have some ground cover that will help keep the weeds from re-establishing and help lock the slope.

I am in mid-Wales (United Kingdom) so summer temperatures are 15-20C (59-68F) and winters can easily hit -5C (23F)

I have considered Phacelia, which is quite a good green manure, but wasn't too sure if it would thrive.

Comment: You don't say where you are, but I would be very tempted to keep the ferns!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you try ivy; it will take some time to become established, but thrives in the most adverse conditions and forms excellent ground cover. I have used it beneath some mature Leylandii trees, where the soil is extremely dry and nothing else will grow, and it is still spreading..

Comment: Don't you then have to worry about the ivy :-)

Comment: Yes it is a pest for us, but I've seen some attractive ground-cover ivy on slopes in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

I'm only quoting a notcutts book here:
 Bergenia, caltha, Cornus canadensis, Cotoneaster low growing forms, Leucothoe, Pulmonaria, Rubus calcycinoides/tricolor, Waldsteiner.
Also:
Ferns, Gaulteria procumbens, Hedera colchia/hibernica, Helleborus, Hosta, Pachysandra terminalis,Pernettya, Polygonum, Rhododendron, Rubus cockburnianus/thibetanus/tricolor, Ruscus aculeatus, Sarcococca humilis, Spiraea thunbergii/x vanhouttei, Symphoricarpos? wouldn't advise that one, Vibrnum davidii and Vinca. 
Although I have seen for geolocking ground on a steep slope- the professionals use willow? not good for ground cover but its roots are good for making matrices for holding back unstable rocky slopes near motorways- hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ivy seems an odd suggestion on the basis that it has proved to grow well where the soil is extremely dry, given the inclusion of *damp slope* in the Title. *Hedera helix* (there are other ivies) can make a nuisance of itself in many settings but it does prefer the soil it lives in to be well-drained.

However *Phacelia* may be an even stranger suggestion if the question is anything like my interpretation of the requirement. For *Phacelia* [GrowVeg](https://www.growveg.co.uk/plants/us-and-canada/how-to-grow-phacelia/) recommends:

> **Soil**
>   Any sunny site with good drainage.
>   **Position**
>   Full sun to partial afternoon shade.
>   **Frost tolerant**
>   Phacelia seedlings can tolerate light frost, but the plants are easily damaged by hard freezes.

"shaded hillside" and "can easily hit -5C" are at odds with the above.

The (rather limited) conditions mentioned by OP include *shade*, *moist* and *ground cover* and selecting "Sunlight: Partial", "Moisture: Moist but well-drained", "Planting places: "Banks and Slopes", "Hardiness: H3", "Habit: Mat forming" and "Native to the United Kingdom" at the [Royal Horticultural Society](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/Search-Form) plant selection site, returns only one result, *Fuchsia procumbens*. Although the OP has not mentioned soil type or pH, this plant can be comfortable in Sand, Chalk, Loam, Clay whether Acid, Alkaline or Neutral ([RHS](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/7514/i-Fuchsia-procumbens-i/Details)).

Other details that might have helped are aspect, exposure and time scale. For "lock the soil" it might have to be a case of choosing priorities - plants that provide ground cover quickly generally have shallow roots.